# jquery datatable tools - Which version of table tools support jquery 1.6.4?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Which version of table tools support jquery 1.6.4 ? Did have version download link. I'm trying to download, but i'm not able to find the old version of table tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find list of versions there:
https://github.com/DataTables/TableTools/releases

Comment: Thanks for reply...Here only source code, this cann't use for  development.

Comment: @user2444474 How about folder media/js inside zip?

Answer (score 1):

Jquery1.6.4 can work well with datatables1.8, so you can download 1.8.[download link](https://datatables.net/blog/DataTables_1.8). btw, the old version has been removed from the site. And you can find full document here:http://datatables.net/index